# how to create an sql table and get the average price for each unique field?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

there's a drop down html element for date for the current month (January 1 to January 30), currency (CAD,GBP,USD).

there's a html table with two columns, hour and price.

part I: how would I create the table in mysql.

I thought about creating two tables. One with columns id, currency. The other table would have columns hour,price,date,currency_id (foreign key). What is the correct solution?

part II:

table has columns: id, market_instrument, price

I came up with. `SELECT avg(price) FROM table WHERE market_instrument="";`

but the expected result was to get average price for each unique market_instrument. what is the correct SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get average price for each unique market_instrument, you need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT market_instrument, avg(price) FROM table GROUP BY market_instrument
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(price) as price,instrument from table 
group by instrument,price
```

hope this helps

Comment: I assume you mean `group by instrument, currency`, otherwise this won't really work

Comment: where do you see the currency column in the second table? If you need a currency you will have to create a foreign key field in the second table and make a join on the first table then group by 3 selected fields.

Comment: The currency_id in his example. If you group by instrument and price as in your answer then you get a result for every different price that there is for instrument (with an average equal to that price).

Answer (score 0):

```
select market_instrument, avg(price) from table group by market_instrument
```

Answer (score 0):

You want it per instrument and (I assume per currency) so:

```
SELECT AVG(price), instrument
FROM table
GROUP BY instrument, currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: If you are only ever going to have the currency code (CAD,GBP,USD) associated with the currency (no name, exchange rate or any other data) then you don't **have** to have a separate table for the currency - just include the currency code instead of the currency ID on your main table.

However, most of the time I would expect other data (such as currency name, etc.) to be associated with the currency - in which case, your proposed design is reasonable, although I would be inclined to combine the hour and date columns as a single datetime column.